# Unable to access child components from parent

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having trouble accessing child components from the parent. The below code outputs 0 for the array length were I expect 3 children? Also, the myChildren observable never receives a change event; therefore I don't think it is a timing issue.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6QiWVSPWQVqRYMAW3x0D)

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, ngAfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child'

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
    template: `
    <div class='box-container'>
      <p>I'm the parent</p>
      <child-component></child-component>
      <child-component></child-component>
      <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit  {
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent, {descendants: true}) myChildren: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit( ) {
    console.log(this.myChildren.toArray().length)
    this.myChildren.changes.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log(myChildren.length);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `@ViewChildren`.  `@ContentChildren` are for `ng-content` tags I think. [link](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/)

Comment: You were correct. I originally coded it with @ViewChildren, but it wasn't working. Turns out myChildren is undefined in ngAfterContentInit using ViewChildren, but is defined in ngAfterViewInit! So, it is working after the two changes. If you post your suggestion as the answer, I will accept.